# How does one learn research methodology?

Tags: research-process, methodology, multidisciplinary

I am a multidisciplinary person. I have a bachelor's degree in computer science and now I'm working on my master's thesis on strategic intelligence studies. The experience I have in writing both of my master's and bachelor's theses, and the experience of using both of quantitative and qualitative methods show me that there are so many things to learn within the scope of research methodology, be it the methods, the paradigms, etc.

So, instead of being lured into one of the related disciplines that I've been exposed to, I'm far more interested in learning the research methodologies which are applicable to them. I want to  learn them all and I want to be able to devise such methods.

Thence my question, where should I begin my journey in learning and mastering research methodology? Is there any university offering such programme?

Comment: I am also interested in the terminology associated with this. Like theory, theorem, hypothesis, assumption, conjecture, lemma, corollary, law, rule, principle, etc. Is that part of the question or should I open a new one? Sorry and thank you.

Comment: I'm really sorry Trylks but I don't have any intention in discussing academic terminologies. If you opened a new discussion, I would be more than glad to jump in :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a strong need for learning research methodologies, and many postgraduate research courses require as prerequisite research methodology evidence.

The good news is that many institutions do offer specific courses in research methods; the better news is that many offer distance learning and there even some MOOC/Open learning options available. Below are some examples that I'm aware of (I'm sure there are many others):

- [Open Learning Initiative](http://oli.cmu.edu/courses/future/empirical-research-methods/) (Open)
- [City University London](http://www.city.ac.uk/courses/cpd/Research-Methodologies-for-Practice-e-learning)
- [University of Birmingham](http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/postgraduate/courses/taught/med/pg-modules/research-methods-%28distance-learning%29.aspx)
- [University of Southampton](http://www.erm.ecs.soton.ac.uk/)
- [Saylor Academy](http://www.saylor.org/courses/psych202a/) (Open)
- [ACS](http://www.acs.edu.au/courses/research-project-iii-377.aspx)

There are also a [squillion books on research methods](http://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/research-methods)

Comment: thank you very much :) I've been reading research methodology books since, I don't know, the time I started to take an interest in it. Now it's time for me to find specific mentors and specialized classes to fill in my gap of knowledge in research methodology.